# Errors in Java code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get the highest and lowest number entered by user.  I got this. I just new in programming.  There are 3 errors.

```
import java.io.*;
public class HighestToLowest
{
    public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{
    {
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        

        double[] input = new double[8];
        int index;
        int highIndex = 0;
        int lowIndex = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter The Scores Of Judges: ");
        for (index = 0; index<8; index++){
             System.out.print("Enter The Score" + (index + 1) + ": ");
             input[index] = Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine()); 
         }

         for (index = 1; index < 8; index++)
             if(input[highIndex] < input[index])
                highIndex = index;


         for (index = 1; index < 8; index++)
             if (input[lowIndex] > input[index])
                 lowIndex = index;

         for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
             sum = sum + input[index];
         try
            {
                input[index] = Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            if(sum>index)
            {
                sum=highIndex;
            }

            if(sum>=index)
            {
                index=lowIndex;
            }                        
        }

        System.out.print("Highest is: + highIndex");
        System.out.print("Lowest is: + lowIndex");

         System.out.printf("The Contestant Receives a total of %.2f", (sum - highIndex - lowIndex)); 



    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: Whenever you have error messages, always post the line giving you the problem and the complete message.

Comment: Next time, try putting the question in the "body" of the question and not the "title".

Comment: Hey guys, let's be a bit nicer to a newcomer and not close his first post immediately, without even allowing him some time to fix it. Commenting on the issues are fine, closing is not.

Comment: @Peter, 8 revisions in less than 8 minutes means a fairly rough start.

Comment: @Tim I have answer to this question where to post?

Answer (score 1):

Although you say there are only 3 errors, there seen to be a bit more

```
public static void main(String []args)throws IOException{ //<- ?
{//<- why two curly brackets?
```

In for loop

```
for (index = 0; index < 8; index++){//<- curl bracket missing?
         sum = sum + input[index];
         try {
              input[index] = Double.parseDouble(dataIn.readLine());
          } catch(IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }

         if(sum>index) {
              sum=highIndex;
          }
          if(sum>=index){
              index=lowIndex;
           }                        
     } // <- or extra curl bracket?
```

This line will print `Highest is: + highIndex`

```
  System.out.print("Highest is: + highIndex");
```

Any thing in `"` `"` is printed as it is.

So change it to

```
 System.out.print("Highest is:" + highIndex);
```

Same applies for

```
  System.out.print("Lowest is: + lowIndex");
```

---

Are you from C programming, this line is correct

```
System.out.printf("The Contestant Receives a total of %.2f", (sum - highIndex - lowIndex));
```

In Java it can also be written as

```
 System.out.println("The Contestant Receives a total of " +  (sum - highIndex - lowIndex));
```